# angular 7 app doesn't run in firefox and runs well in chrome and edge

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

My angular 7 app works fine in chrome and edge but for some reason doesn't load in firefox and i get this error:

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
>   {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown
>   Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
>   failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown
>   Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}"

from core-js.

My dependencies:

```
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
```

and firefox version is the latest one

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not an angular issue, but more like server side. Pasting the solution from the following page to avoid being lost:

Change

```
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

to

```
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': '/' });
```

and set restricted xml type in WebApiConfig file as:

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12695